# Font Awesome icons not displaying in IE 10 on local install, but do show up on CDN

Tags: internet-explorer, font-awesome

I've tried everything I can find in stackoverflow and on the web and I can't figure out how to fix it.

If I use maxcdn for Font Awesome, IE 10/11 are happy and I can see the icons.  If I use the local bower install, no icons.

When I look at the network tab for maxcdn, I see the following:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0
```

When I look at the network tab for local bower, I see the following:

```
/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?
/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0
/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0
```

The response header for the local bower install is:
[image]

I'm guessing that the answer is in the response header, but not sure what or how to fix it.

Help please!
Julie

Comment: I'm thinking the problem has to do with the "Cache-Control" in the response header, but don't know how to fix it or what to try.  The simple fix would be to use maxcdn, but I can't go external and need to do everything local.

Comment: When the request is made from either Chrome or IE to maxcdn, the response comes back as HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified.  But when the request is made from IE locally, the response is HTTP/1.1 200 OK.

Comment: I think I need to remove 'no-store' from the Cache-Control on our nginx server and now need to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my problem was to remove:

Pragma "no-cache"

from the headers being served by our nginx.

I do not know why this fixed the problem, but it did....

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, the actual cause was https secured connection

I was using https protocol changed it to http

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Best is to remove the protocol all together: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  this will work in either case.